# lion: assign buttons on a Microsoft mouse

Tags: mouse

I have an old 5 button Microsoft mouse (Laser Mouse 6000) and forever I've assigned the thumb button to "back" in the browser and the middle mouse button to "next app" on the desktop. Since I've installed Lion, this doesn't seem to work. The settings in the "Microsoft Mouse" panel in System Preferences don't seem have any effect.

Is there another way to map mouse buttons? I've noticed that Mission Control seems to detect my 5 buttons and let me assign them, but only to Mission Control functions. I don't see anywhere else where I can do this. Do I just need to wait for new MS drivers? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/)**'s "Normal Mouse" area allows you to assign functions to all kinds of mouse buttons and should work for you. It's free, too, so it won't hurt to try.

The author has issued a couple of recent updates to make it more compatible with Lion. There are still a couple of small things but I'm using it every day (previously with my mouse, now with my trackpad) and it's tremendously useful.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this. It has solved my back button problem. I still can't quite get my app switching back. Basically I used to be able to hit my mouse wheel button to bring up the switcher, scroll the wheel to choose an item, and then release the button to select. I'll keep digging into this tool to see what it can do.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out I just needed to install the most recent version of the MS drivers. Everything now works like it did.

The latest MS Drivers can be found at: http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads (the versions in the MS Downloads Center, and in Google results are older which don't work with Lion)